# Loose tooth. Suck it up and pull?

Tags: teeth

I am a kid. I have a loose tooth where the part is off but the other part isn't. I can see my new tooth underneath. Should i just suck it up and push with my tongue?
 It's a bottom left molar

Comment: Again, NOT parent.

Comment: doesnt hurt to wait

Comment: As the new tooth is already there, I suggest "toying with the loose tooth" - especially if it's really loose. Don't wait too long (as in days), but don't rip a tooth that's still stuck. "Fiddling" with it will gradually loosen it. And of course you could always opt for the dentist, but that's probably overkill.

Comment: Hi Aria, welcome to Parenting.SE! This is really similar to a question that was already asked ([When to pull loose teeth](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7858/when-to-pull-loose-teeth)) so read through those answers to learn more about loosing teeth and when you "need" to pull. Personally, I'd suggest wiggling it as long as it isn't hurting too much — sometimes a little extra help is all it needs to fall out!